# Portable Contacts for PHP?

Tags: php, portable-contacts

I can see Google is implementing the [Portable Contacts](http://portablecontacts.net/) API for developers to fetch a user's contacts. That seems like exactly what I want to do and I especially like the fact that the protocol is open and through it I can support more than *just* Google.

What I'd like to know is whether there is a library for PHP that implements this protocol, as I don't feel like writing one from scratch / reinventing the wheel.

I wouldn't generally post such questions which could be answered by simply googling, but I've done my googling on the subject and can't seem to find any relevant info.

BTW, I don't use Zend, so please don't suggest that to me, unless it's the only way possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Open Social PHP Client](http://code.google.com/p/opensocial-php-client/) can access the Portable Contacts API